# What format when excluding processes from Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-8, windows-defender

I find the Windows Defender 'Excluded processes' window confusing. This is the screen I am referring to:

[image: Windows Defender excluded processes screen]

I would expect just to enter the name of a process, e.g., **devenv.exe**, but the *Browse* button makes me think I need a full path name. Here are three questions:

- Do I need to enter full path names?
- Can I use wildcards? * and ?
- Is there any way I can tell whether a process is being excluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need a full path name, and wildcards are not supported. As far as testing if an executable is being excluded, run a scan on the folder it is in, and view the details of the search.

Answer (score 4):

As of Windows 10, there are 3 ways to specify process exclusions. Note that the process exclusions mean that no files opened by the excluded process will be scanned.

**Any file on the machine that is opened by any process with a specific file name**

Specifying "test.exe" would exclude files opened by:

- c:\sample\test.exe
- d:\internal\files\test.exe

**Any file on the machine that is opened by any process under a specific folder**

Specifying "c:\test\sample\*" would exclude files opened by:

- c:\test\sample\test.exe
- c:\test\sample\test2.exe
- c:\test\sample\utility.exe

**Any file on the machine that is opened by a specific process in a specific folder**

- Specifying "c:\test\process.exe" would exclude files only opened by c:\test\process.exe

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-process-opened-file-exclusions-windows-defender-antivirus)

Comment: Then what would it mean to specify "C:\test\sampe\" without a wild card? Still using the option to exclude a process (not the exclude a folder option).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this TechNet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/clientsecurity/archive/2010/03/08/wildcards-in-path-exclusions.aspx), wildcards *are* supported, but only for on-demand scans (e.g. scheduled scans or requested scans) and not for realtime protection (scanning when the file is accessed or modified).